# Why do I have C# code in my C++ Windows Form and C++ functions are popping errors?

Tags: c#, c++, winforms

I have an assignment of building a simple calculator as a C++ Windows Form.

For now it is one TextBox and One button, sample input to the TextBox is `3 + 2` and the button should print their result on the same TextBox.

I created a New Project -> C++ Windows Form:

[image]

But some codes were generated automatically, which look like C# codes and I did not see before.

Original code after adding the Button and the TextBox:

```
#pragma once

namespace CppWinForm1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(59, 81);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(59, 31);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(282, 253);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion

    }

    };
}
```

And when I add my stuff in the above file (MyForm.h):

```
#include <string>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h> // for converting String^ to string

using namespace std;

// ..

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    System::String^ temp = textBox1->Text; // system string
    std::string InputString = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(temp); // convert to standard string

    int FirstNumber = 0,
        SecondNumber = 0,
        Result = 0,
        MyInc = 1;
    char MyOperator;

    int SpaceIndex = InputString.find(' ');

    for (int i = SpaceIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        FirstNumber += InputString[i].ToInt32() * MyInc;
        MyInc *= 10;
    }

    MyOperator = InputString[SpaceIndex + 1];

    InputString = InputString.substr(0, SpaceIndex + 2);

    MyInc = 1;

    for (int i = InputString.length() -1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        FirstNumber += InputString[i].ToInt32() * MyInc;
        MyInc *= 10;
    }

    if (MyOperator == '+')
        Result = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;

    textBox1->Text = Result.ToString();
```

I get this error on .ToInt32() function:

> Too few arguments for the function call

Also in MyForm.Cpp (Which I did not touch) there is the same error:

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^ args) // Error here saying too few Arguments
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    CppWinForm1::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Could someone point me on why this is happening? Please and Thanks

Comment: Could it be that Microsoft wants all GUIs written in Microsoft's language C#?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I know that C++ was not designed for GUIs. I remember doing a simple C++ WinForm in class. I want to do the same. And I have never seen C# with it. Am I doing anything wrong? And how can I fix the errors so it builds at least

Comment: Many people despise Microsoft and C# and use GUI frameworks that support C++ (e.g. wxWidgets & QT).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: The code is **not** C#. And Microsoft totally supports producing GUIs using C++ (be it plain Windows API applications, or modern UI, based on WinRT). Few people I know *"despise"* Microsoft.

Comment: What is `InputString[i].ToInt32()` supposed to be? `InputString` is a `std::string`, so `InputString[i]` is a character, which does not have any methods. Did you want to write `Convert.ToInt32(InputString[i])`?

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes. I meant to convert the char to an int. But also `Convert` pops an error saying `type name is not allowed`. Is that C++ btw?

Comment: Oh, my bad. `std::string` uses `char` and `Convert.ToInt32` expects `wchar_t` in C++/CLI. you should do what @IInspectable suggests in his answer. (Also all of that code is kind of C++, as explained in the answer. It's just a superset developed by Microsoft)

Comment: @UnholySheep What about the error that is in the .cpp file? Which I did not touch.. Conversion can be researched, but that `^>^` is confusing, with an error..

Comment: `array<String^>^` is once again C++/CLI syntax. the `^` means that it's a handle (and garbage collected) which work similarly to pointers in standard C++. The syntax should be correct, I'm inclined to believe that it's just a misreported error (caused by the other errors in your code). It should disappear once you fix the others

Comment: @UnholySheep I fixed the other error, but this one stayed. I tried to just remove all parameters (like normal `int main()` in c++) and it worked :D Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generated code is C++/CLI, a superset of Standard C++. Note, that it's not C#. There are a number of differences, e.g. the namespace separator being `::` vs `.`, or the `ref class` contextual keyword. C++/CLI compiles to MSIL (managed code), but can contain native C++, producing a so-called *mixed-mode* assembly. It's primarily used for managed/unmanaged interop.

The compiler error you receive for `InputString[i].ToInt32()` is a bit misleading. It's a result of the complexity of the language, the compiler trying all potential ways to interpret an expression, and when it finally gives up, the error it encountered is not always the most comprehensible one.

In this case, `InputString[i]` invokes [`std::string::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at), which returns a reference to `char`. This is an integral data type in C++, not a class type with member methods. If you need to convert a string or character to an integer, you'd have to use another means, e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
int number = std::stoi(std::string(InputString[i]));
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the information. What about fixing the errors?

Comment: @SandraK: You'd have to provide the complete error message. That includes the line of code that raised it.

Comment: I did. I have it on both files as well

Comment: @SandraK: [`std::string::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) returns a `const char&`. It's an integral data type of C++, that doesn't have any class members (like `ToInt32`). To convert a `std::string` (or a single character) to an integer, you'd use [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) or similar.

Comment: But the debugger suggested `ToInt32` to me when I typed `.`. I will research that or similar. Thanks

Comment: @SandraK the debugger didn't suggest anything. That was IntelliSense (which is an autocompleter/code analyzer/... and part of Visual Studio) and it is known to occasionally suggest wrong code, especially in C++/CLI (which is part of the reason most programmers use C# instead for GUI programming)

Comment: @SandraK: As I explained in the answer, the language is complex, and both the compiler as well as the compiler frontend (feeding the Intellisense suggestions) can fail. In this case I believe that the compiler winds up looking for *extension methods*. Don't trust Intellisense, and that goes for every language. It's often right, but sometimes fails (unless you're using C#, VB.NET, or VB6).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the conversion function. As well it is worth mentioning that I just removed all the parameters of `main()` and I don't know why, but no more errors and it compiled fine.

Comment: @SandraK: `int main()` is a valid entry point signature for a C++/CLI application. Still, `void Main(array<String^>^)` should be equally valid. I can only guess, that failure to compile this is a result of other errors. Anyway, using `int main()` has no adverse effect.